# Как сделать модальное окно в модальном окне?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть форма с всплывающим модальным окном, в этом окне есть ссылка на еще модальное окно (т.е. ссылка Политики Конфиденциальности).

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы при клике на ссылку "Политики конфиденциальности" выскакивала модальное окно поверх формы модального окна.

Пример: [image: Только вместо "Отлично ваше сообщение отправлено" выскакивала плашка с политикой конфиденциальности.]

```js
$(document).ready(function() { // вся мaгия пoсле зaгрузки стрaницы
  $('.btn-bay').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline'
  });
  $(".product").val($('.btn-bay').attr('data-name'));
  $(document).on('click', '#modal_close', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.magnificPopup.close();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  //E-mail Ajax Send
  $("form").submit(function() { //Change
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "send.php", //Change
      data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
      swal({
        title: "Отлично!",
        text: "Ваше сообщение отправлено",
        icon: "success",
        button: "Хорошо",
      });
      setTimeout(function() {
        $.magnificPopup.close();
      }, 1000);

    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="submit btn-bay" href="#form" data-name="Белый">Заказать</a>

<div class="hidden">
  <form action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call(this)" method="post" id="form">
    <span id="modal_close"><img src="img/25/close.svg"></span>
    <!-- Кнoпкa зaкрыть -->
    <div class="callback-form__title">Отличный выбор!</div>
    <div class="inputs">
      <div class="input">
        <label class="header">Введите имя *</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="callback-form__field" placeholder="Иван Иванов">
      </div>
      <div class="input">
        <label class="header">Введите телефон *</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="callback-form__field" placeholder="+7 (945) 777-00-00" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="product" class="product">
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="<?=@$_GET['utm_source']?>">
    <button type="submit" class="callback-form__btn btn">Заказать </button>
    <p class="politic">Заполняя форму, вы соглашаетесь с<br><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Политикой Конфиденциальности</a></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: ровно так же как любое другое окно в другом окне...

Comment: Можете более подробно описать